# Change color of the rectangle which the mouse is in by using the mouse wheel

Tags: java, graphics, rectangles

Sorry for posting my whole code but this way you can check my problem easier, no?

```
package task3;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import javax.swing.*;

class Model {
    
    int l; //line
    int c; //column
    int[] loc = {0,0}; //location
    JFrame frame;
    int m_width;
    int m_height;
    int R;
    int G;
    int B;
    int count;
    int mY;
    int x, y;
    Rectangle rect;
    
    
    int genR() {
    int R = (int)(Math.random()*256);
        return R;
    }
    int genG() {
        int G = (int)(Math.random()*256); 
        return G;
    }
    int genB() {
        int B = (int)(Math.random()*256);
        return B;
    }
    
    public int getRectWidth() {
        return frame.getContentPane().getWidth() / c;
    }
    public int getRectHeight() {
        return frame.getContentPane().getHeight() / l;
    }
    
    
    Model(int width, int height, int line, int column, JFrame w) {
        m_width = width;
        m_height = height;
        l = line;
        c = column;
        frame = w;
    }
}

class Mvl extends JComponent implements MouseWheelListener {
    
    private Model m_Mod;
    
    Mvl(Model mod) {
        m_Mod = mod;
    }
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        //m_Mod.mY += e.getWheelRotation();
        //m_Mod.mY += e.getUnitsToScroll();
        System.out.print(m_Mod.rect.getSize());
        m_Mod.frame.repaint();
        //int x = e.getXOnScreen();
        //int y = e.getYOnScreen();
        //int x = e.getX();
        //int y = e.getY();

       
         //RectangleComponent rc = new RectangleComponent(x, y);
         //m_Mod.frame.add(rc);
         //m_Mod.frame.revalidate();
    }
}

class Reactmouse implements MouseListener { //Print size of rectangle //Implement all methods otherwise abstract class
    
    private Model m_Mod;
    
    Reactmouse(Model mod) {
        m_Mod = mod;
    }
    
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { 
        //System.out.println(++m_Mod.count + "  " + "Width: " + m_Mod.getRectWidth() + "  " + "Height: " +
        //m_Mod.getRectWidth() + " Position X-Axis: " + m_Mod.loc[0] + "Position Y-Axis: " + m_Mod.loc[1]);
        System.out.println("Position on X-Axis:" + e.getX() + " " + "Position on Y-Axis: "+  e.getY()); 
        //Cords of the click, in the rectangle
    }
    
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { 
        
    }
}

class View extends JComponent {
    
    private Model m_Mod;

    View(Model mod) {
        m_Mod = mod;
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        Color c = new Color(m_Mod.genR(), m_Mod.genG(), m_Mod.genB());
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillRect(m_Mod.loc[0], m_Mod.loc[1], m_Mod.getRectWidth(), m_Mod.getRectHeight());
        m_Mod.rect = g.getClipBounds(); 
    }
```

Here I ask for the size's Dimension but I need the rectangle's size

```
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
    
        for(int i=0; i<m_Mod.l; ++i) {
            for(int j=0; j<m_Mod.c; ++j) {
                
              draw(g);  
              m_Mod.loc[0] = m_Mod.loc[0] + m_Mod.getRectWidth() + 2;
              
             }
            
            m_Mod.loc[0] = 0;
            m_Mod.loc[1] = m_Mod.loc[1] + m_Mod.getRectHeight() + 2;
        }
        m_Mod.loc[1] = 0;
    }
}
class Controller extends JFrame{
    
    private Model m_Mod;
    private View m_View;
    
    
        Controller(){
                
                JFrame window = new JFrame();
                m_Mod = new Model(500,500,8,8, window);
                m_View = new View(m_Mod);
                Image icon = window.getToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\49157\\eclipse-workspace\\Programmierung\\src\\task3\\download.png");
                window.setIconImage(icon);
                window.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
                window.add(m_View);
                window.setSize(m_Mod.m_width,m_Mod.m_height);
                //window.add(new myButton());
                window.addMouseWheelListener(new Mvl(m_Mod));
                window.addMouseListener(new Reactmouse(m_Mod));
                window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                window.setVisible(true);
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                
        }
        void simulate(){
            m_View.repaint();
        }
        
}
public class task3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            
            Controller c = new Controller();    
            c.simulate();
            
        }
    }
```

Okay so I can redraw the whole frame with my mousewheel but I can not redraw single rectangles drawed here. How do I do that?

The main problem is that I cannot ask for the x and y coords of my drawed rectangles. Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain your code and your problem in greater detail. You seem to be leaving out a bit of information.

Comment: Sure, my code paints a frame with given size. Then it paints given rectangles in line and column in random color. Now I want to click on a single rectangle and change its color by spinning my mouse wheel.

Comment: Please [edit] and improve the question itself. Tell even more.

Comment: You have a ... few problems. You really need to seperate the concept of your "virtual" and "physical" models.  That is, you have a "virtual" model which describes the number of rows and columns you'd like to display and the "physical" model which describes the "boxes", their position in the UI, the relationship back to the "virtual" model (row/column) and their color. Depending on if you want this size to be fixed or not will change the way that the physical model will be created. But from this, you can use the "physical" model to determine what's been clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Introduction

Since your code is not runnable, I went ahead and created an example GUI.  Here's the example GUI.

[image: Colored Rectangles 1]

Here's the example GUI after I changed a couple of colors.

[image: Colored Rectangles 2]

## Explanation

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

When I create a Swing GUI, I use the [model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern.  This pattern allows me to separate my code into small logical methods and lets me focus on one small part of the problem at a time.

The MVC pattern implies that you create the model first, then the view, then finally the controller.  You iterate between the model, view, and controller.  For this GUI, I created a basic model and added fields to the model as I went along.

In Swing, the MVC pattern means:

- The view reads information from the model.
- The view does not update the model.
- The controller(s) update the model and repaint/revalidate the view.

Model classes are plain Java getter/setter classes.  View classes use or extend Swing components.

Generally, each Swing action or listener acts as its own controller, responsible for its portion of the model and view.  There's not one controller class "to rule them all".

For this application, I created two model classes, two view classes, and two mouse listener classes.

### Model

The `ColorRectangle` class holds a background `Color` and a `java.awt.Rectangle` to hold the position and size of the rectangle.

The `ColoredRectanglesModel` class holds a two-dimensional array of `ColorRectangle` instances and an array of possible background colors.  This class creates the model that the view uses to create the GUI.

### View

The `ColoredRectangles` class creates the `JFrame`.  This is a pretty standard `JFrame` setup, and it forms the start of almost all of my Swing applications.

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

The `DrawingPanel` class draws the rectangles.  Period.  Nothing else.

I override the `paintComponent` method.  The first call is to the `super.paintComponent` method, which draws the `JPanel` background and maintains the Swing paint chain.

### Controller

The `RectangleListener` class lets the user select which rectangle will be modified.

The `ColorListener` class scrolls through the possible background colors using the mouse wheel.

Notice how simple both these classes are.  The heavy lifting is done by the model classes.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ColoredRectangles implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ColoredRectangles());
    }
    
    private final ColoredRectanglesModel model;
    
    private final DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    public ColoredRectangles() {
        this.model = new ColoredRectanglesModel();
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(this, model);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Colored Rectangles");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private final ColoredRectanglesModel model;
        
        public DrawingPanel(ColoredRectangles view, ColoredRectanglesModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            this.setPreferredSize(model.getDrawingDimension());
            this.addMouseListener(new RectangleListener(model));
            this.addMouseWheelListener(new ColorListener(view, model));
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            
            ColorRectangle[][] coloredRectangles = model.getColoredRectangles();
            for (int i = 0; i < coloredRectangles.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < coloredRectangles[i].length; j++) {
                    g2d.setColor(coloredRectangles[i][j].getBackgroundColor());
                    Rectangle r = coloredRectangles[i][j].getRectangle();
                    g2d.fillRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public class RectangleListener extends MouseAdapter {
        
        private final ColoredRectanglesModel model;

        public RectangleListener(ColoredRectanglesModel model) {
            this.model = model;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            model.setSelectedRectangle(event.getPoint());
        }
        
    }
    
    public class ColorListener extends MouseAdapter {

        private final ColoredRectangles view;

        private final ColoredRectanglesModel model;

        public ColorListener(ColoredRectangles view,
                ColoredRectanglesModel model) {
            this.view = view;
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent event) {
            if (model.getSelectedRectangle() != null) {
                model.incrementColorIndex(event.getWheelRotation());
                ColorRectangle r = model.getSelectedRectangle();
                r.setBackgroundColor(model.getCurrentColor());
                view.repaint();
            }
        }

    }
    
    public class ColoredRectanglesModel {
        
        private int colorIndex;
        
        private final ColorRectangle[][] coloredRectangles;
        private ColorRectangle selectedRectangle;
        
        private final Color[] colors;
        private Color currentColor;
        
        private Dimension drawingDimension;
        
        private final Random random;
        
        public ColoredRectanglesModel() {
            this.colorIndex = 0;
            this.random = new Random();
            this.colors = generateColors();
            this.coloredRectangles = generateColoredRectangles();
            this.currentColor = colors[colorIndex];
        }
        
        private Color[] generateColors() {
            return new Color[] { Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.LIGHT_GRAY,
                    Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK, Color.RED,
                    Color.WHITE, Color.YELLOW };
        }
        
        private ColorRectangle[][] generateColoredRectangles() {
            ColorRectangle[][] coloredRectangles = new ColorRectangle[4][3];
            
            int x = 20;
            int y = 20;
            int width = 128;
            int height = 128;
            int maxWidth = 0;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < coloredRectangles.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < coloredRectangles[i].length; j++) {
                    int index = random.nextInt(colors.length);
                    Color color = colors[index];
                    coloredRectangles[i][j] = new ColorRectangle(color, x, y,
                            width, height);
                    x += width + 20;
                }
                maxWidth = x;
                x = 20;
                y += height + 20;
            }
            
            this.drawingDimension = new Dimension(maxWidth, y);
            
            return coloredRectangles;
        }
        
        public void setSelectedRectangle(Point point) {
            for (int i = 0; i < coloredRectangles.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < coloredRectangles[i].length; j++) {
                    Rectangle r = coloredRectangles[i][j].getRectangle();
                    if (r.x <= point.x && r.x + r.width >= point.x
                            && r.y <= point.y && r.y + r.height >= point.y) {
                        this.selectedRectangle = coloredRectangles[i][j];
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            this.selectedRectangle = null;
        }
        
        public void incrementColorIndex(int increment) {
            colorIndex += increment;
            if (colorIndex < 0) {
                colorIndex = colors.length + colorIndex;
            } else {
                colorIndex %= colors.length;
            }
            this.currentColor = colors[colorIndex];
        }

        public ColorRectangle[][] getColoredRectangles() {
            return coloredRectangles;
        }

        public Dimension getDrawingDimension() {
            return drawingDimension;
        }

        public ColorRectangle getSelectedRectangle() {
            return selectedRectangle;
        }

        public Color getCurrentColor() {
            return currentColor;
        }

    }
    
    public class ColorRectangle {

        private Color backgroundColor;

        private final Rectangle rectangle;

        public ColorRectangle(Color backgroundColor, int x, int y, int width,
                int height) {
            this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
            this.rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        }

        public void setBackgroundColor(Color backgroundColor) {
            this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        }

        public Color getBackgroundColor() {
            return backgroundColor;
        }

        public Rectangle getRectangle() {
            return rectangle;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. This is way too much for my beginner's mind but thank you so much. I will need some time to understand what exactly happened in your code.